# Why does web-scrapping program will not produce any data?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

It is a simple web-scrapping program using BeauifulSoup that should extract specific pieces of data, customer reviews, from an Amazon product site. A few months ago it was working, but for some implicit reason it stopped working and producing any data. I was looking for the community's general thoughts and ideas for now and I can provide you with the steps I took to troubleshoot the issue upon request.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd

reviewlist = []

# driver = driver.Chrome(f'https://www.amazon.com/Futurebiotics-Ashwagandha-Capsules-Strength-Serving/product-reviews/B09KHK2FPF/ref=cm_cr_getr_d_paging_btm_prev_1?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews&pageNumber={x}')

def get_soup(url):
    # {'http://localhost:8050/render.html', params={'url': url, 'wait': 2}
    r = requests.get(url)
    # r.proxies = {}
    # r.proxies['http'] = 'socks5h://localhost:3000'
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    return soup


def get_reviews(soup):
    reviews = soup.find_all('div', {'data-hook': 'review'})
    try:
        for item in reviews:
            review = {
            'ProductName': soup.title.text.replace('Amazon.com: Customer reviews:', '').strip(),
            # 'user_name': item.find('span', {'class': 'a-profile-name'}).text.strip(),
            'Country_Date': item.find('span', {'data-hook': 'review-date'}).text.strip(),
            'title_stars': item.find('a', {'data-hook': 'review-title'}).text.strip(),
            'rating': float(item.find('i', {'data-hook': 'review-star-rating'}).text.replace('out of 5 stars', '').strip()),
            'body': item.find('span', {'data-hook': 'review-body'}).text.strip(),
            }
            reviewlist.append(review)
    except:
        pass

for x in range(1,999):
    soup = get_soup(f'https://www.amazon.com/Endurox-R4-Tangy-Orange-4-56/product-reviews/B00029F5LS/ref=cm_cr_getr_d_paging_btm_next_{x}?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews&pageNumber={x}')
    print(f'Getting page: {x}')
    get_reviews(soup)
    print(len(reviewlist))
    if not soup.find('li', {'class': 'a-disabled a-last'}):
        pass
    else:
        break

df = pd.DataFrame(reviewlist)
df.to_excel('4.xlsx', index=False)re
```

I am expecting some feedback and insight to resolve this problem.

Comment: Probably javascript. Need [tag:selenium].

Comment: You have the Selenium code commented out. You almost certainly need that.

Comment: What is the value of `r.text`? Does it contain the reviews you expect?